# How to program the ADC10 on an MSP430G2553?

Tags: c, assembly, msp430, adc

I am currently writing my first serious application with an MSP430 controller (specifically, an MSP430G2553) and I am a bit confused by the documentation as to how I'm supposed to set up the ADC10. I want to use it like this:

- The signal (coming from a 100 kΩ potentiometer between V<sub>CC</sub> and GND) is connected to input A4 (pin 6) and is in range from GND to V<sub>CC</sub>
- Once in a while (when the user presses a button) I want to sample the voltage at that input. One sample is sufficient.
- I have enough time to do whatever is needed to sample input when the time to do so arrives.
- I'd prefer to do this synchronously (i.e. without interrupts) as to not complicate the program logic too much.
- The ADC10 should be turned off when I'm not using it to conserve power.
- Neither the ADC10 nor ping 6 is used in any other way in this application.

How do I configure and use the ADC10 in this use case? I am programming the MSP430 in assembly, but an answer in C is useful, too.

Here is how I think the ADC is supposed to be configured:

```
ADC10CTL0:
  SREFx      = 000  (V_CC)
  ADC10SHTx  = 11   (64 clocks, we have enough time)
  ADC10SR    = 1    (50 kbps should be enough)
  REFOUT     = 0
  REFBURST   = don't care
  MSC        = don't care
  REF2_5V    = don't care
  REFON      = 0
  ADC10ON    = 1    (set to 1 after finishing the configuration)
  ADC10IE    = 0    (no interrupts)

ADC10CTL1
  INCHx      = 0100 (A4)
  SHSx       = 00   (sample and hold sourced from ADC10SC)
  ADC10DF    = 0    (no two's complement)
  ISSH       = 0    (no inversion)
  ADC10DIVx  = 000  (not too sure either)
  ADC10SSELx = 0    (is this the right clock?)
  CONSEQx    = 00   (single channel single conversion)

ADC10AE0     = 0x10 (A4 enabled)
ADC10DTC1    = 0    (DTC disabled)
```

I think the sequence to sample data looks like this:

1. set `ADC10ON` to 1, `ENC` and `ADC10SC` to 0 and configure all the registers.
2. set `ADC10SC` and `ENC` to 10 to start conversion
3. wait for 64 + 12 + 1 = 77 cycles for conversion to finish
4. read result from `ADC10MEM`

Is this sequence correct? Are the settings correct?

Comment: Please choose assembler or C. Answers will be very different. (personal recommendation: choose C; assembler programming - except for small stubs - makes little sense nowadays).

Comment: Note: this is no code-writing service. Plase show what you have done so far and where your actualy problem is. Upps, sorry, did not look at the poster. FuZxxI, you should know better

Comment: I'd start with the FUG (family user's guide). Just set the registers as given in the ADC10 section and port selection.

Comment: yeah sure, give me a moment, I'm on a train right now.

Comment: @Olaf As I say in the question, I'm mostly interested in assembly code but if you prefer to provide an answer in C, that's okay, too.

Comment: @Olaf I've added my idea of how I think the ADC is supposed to be used.

Comment: I think the basic idea is correct. But as I have not worked with that particular device or ADC10 yet, I' not sure. Just try. TIming depends on the system clock. Do not forget to set the PIN correctly (IIRC, MSP430 needs to passivate the analog inputs from digital circuitry, there should be a register for the port).

Comment: @Olaf What about the bits I have no idea about?

Comment: I had to read myself and get deeper into this than I actually want to right now - to be honest (please(!) understand, I have my own large project). For now, I try to give you pointers. I'm pretty sure there are some app-notes, to from TI. Have you checked microcontroller.net? They might be able to provide more help. At least it is a forum and more suited than SO.

Comment: The bits are described in the FUG pretty well.

Comment: @Olaf Okay, I thing I have an idea of what to fill in for the remaining settings. I'd really like to know if all of this is correct because it's quite hard to test this in a program as I have no mean to output any data while the program is running (no pins left for UART) and I can't accurately test the timing when the debugger is running. I just want someone to say “jepp, this is correct” at this point.

Comment: Ok, `REFBURST` depends on power management. `MSC` is don't care if not multiple/sequence mode. SHSx depends on your sample-trigger. If you start manually, set to 0 (ADC10SC bit). For the rest you really have to check your hardware setup. Timing depends on which clock, frequency, etc. Normally, I would start with the basic setup, then using peripherals, etc.

Comment: You can get the output by changing a timer period and connecting a simple piezzo (no integrated electronics) to a timer-output (with simple transistor-inverter, do not connect directly: high voltage (or use a series resistor plus zehner diode). Just ask someone at the HU or a friend with electrotechnic background if you feel lost about that.

Comment: @Olaf I can of course let an LED blink or something like that but I can't be sure this way if the output is correct (it might be that I'm always reading the output from the last time or something like this). I think `REFBURST` is not needed as I'm not using the reference voltage generator.

Comment: LED is not good for such, as the dynamic range is too small. Your ears can track a much larger range. YOu can also use a frequency counter (some multimeters have one) - that might even give quite a precise reading. To get someone saying "it works!" he would need to have the same hardware and write the code for you actually ...

Comment: @Olaf Still, this won't tell me if I'm accidentally reading the last result or if there is any Heisenbug. I prefer to know if I'm doing things right instead of saying “looks like it works,” which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Mostly because “looks like it works” quit often means “no, it doesn't work but you won't see it fail until it's too late.”

Comment: "... always reading the output from the last time ..." well, if you see a change when turning the potentiometer, that sounds quite correct to me. Otherwise you would need a scope plus signal generator to track input and output, expecting a (near) constant delay for rechtangular input to output.

Comment: @Olaf I will also see change if I'm always seeing the penultimate change. I'd really like to be certain. This is leading me nowhere without someone who can say “yes, you're doing it right.” (or the other way round).

Comment: "... I'd really like to be certain ...." Welcome in the wonderful world of low-cost bare-metal embedded systems programming!

Comment: Have tried using GRACE from TI .

Comment: This questions suits **Embedded System** SE site. Can you please re-post this question there ?

Comment: @prasad What's that? Is it possible to migrate my question?

Comment: @prasad Are you sure it does not belong here? I find many similar questions on this site.

Comment: Yes You are right. But there is overlapping questions. And Being a firmware related it belongs to **Embedded System** SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings look correct.  I get the feeling you're unsure about clocking, though.

In your sampling sequence, keep `ADC10ON` set to 0 until the rest of the registers are configured.  Then, when you are waiting to sample, don't wait a specific number of cycles.  Instead, poll `ADC10BUSY` until it is 0.

The 64 clocks referenced in the sample-and-hold time setting `ADC10SHTx` are not CPU (MCLK) clocks; they are clocks relative to whatever clock source you select with the `ADC10SSELx` setting, divided by the `ADC10DIVx` value.

With your current settings your ADC is running from the `ADC10OSC` (ADC's internal oscillator) which runs at roughly 5 MHz, and you're dividing that clock by 1.  Your sample time is set to 64 clocks, or 12.8 µs.  You could multiply this sample time by 2, 4, or 8 by dividing the clock by the same value.

What your sample time needs to be depends on your hardware -- specifically, how long it would take for your voltage source to fill a particular capacitor.  If you don't wait long enough, you'll still get a reading, but it will be incorrect.  The MSP430 Family User's Guide has more detail.  However, the "just make it go; I have all the time in the world" setting would be to use the ACLK source (12kHz assuming ACLK is sourced internally from the VLO) divided by 8 (=1.5kHz) with 64-clock samples for a 42ms sample time.  It will actually take 77 clocks as you've calculated above, so the reading will take roughly 51ms to complete.  This is really slow and gross overkill, but it's not a bad starting point to tune from.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tested the setup described above (I poll `ADC10BUSY` instead of waiting though) with the clock being a 512 Hz clock (external 32768 Hz oscillator divided by 64) and it seems to work so far. Thank you for your answer, it helps me.